# Is there a keyboard shortcut for switching between different desktops of the same application?

Tags: macos, keyboard, shortcut

There's the shortcut Cmd+tab for switching between open applications. Then there's the shortcut Cmd+` for switching between open windows of the same application. But if I have the same application open in two different desktops, neither of these shortcuts are really applicable. Cmd+tab to an app with multiple simultaneous desktop instances just goes to the desktop for that app that you were most recently using. Cmd+` does nothing.

For instance, I have the terminal version of emacs in one desktop. Then I have another desktop with some terminals. How can I easily switch between these desktops using only my keyboard?  The easiest way I see is to three-finger swipe up on the trackpad and use the trackpad to select the desired desktop.

I'm on Catalina, version 10.15.6.

Comment: You can assign `Cmd-#` to each Desktop.  So, if you want to switch to the 3rd desktop space, you’d press `Cmd-3`. As for Terminal, look at iTerm2.  It will automatically assign shortcuts to each open Tab and Window allowing you to select them from anywhere

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How can I easily switch between these desktops using only my keyboard?

Here is a screen shot of **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts** > **Mission Control** for two **Desktops**.

As you can see, by default, you can use **control-left-arrow** or **control-right-arrow**

You can also check the checkboxes for additional options, e.g.:

- **Switch to Desktop 1**
- **Switch to Desktop 2**

Then you can use, e.g., **⌘1** or **⌘** and the **Desktop** *number* for whichever you want to move to.

[image]

**Terminal** also assigns a *keyboard shortcut* for up to nine *windows*, e.g. **⌥⌘1** etc. up to **⌥⌘9**